# How to detect character encoding from stream

Tags: javascript, node.js, stream, character-encoding, bigdata

I want to get the character encoding of large file data acquired by stream in js (e.g. SJIS, UTF8).

I could get it by converting stream to buffer, but I can't convert it to buffer if the data is about 2GB.

test1.

```
const encodingJapanese: any = require('encoding-japanese');

const bufferData: Buffer = await this.streamToBuffer(fileData);
console.log('character :', encodingJapanese.detect(bufferData));

async streamToBuffer(data: any): Promise<Buffer> {
    const convToBuffer: any = (stream: any): any =>
      new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any): any => {
        const chunks: any = [];
        stream.on('data', (chunk: any) => chunks.push(chunk));
        stream.on('error', (error: any) => reject(error));
        stream.on('end', () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)));
      });
    return await convToBuffer(data);
}
```

With 400MB of data, I could get the character code of fileData with the code shown above, but with 2GB of data, the process fails at the `(Buffer.concat(chunks))` part.

test2.

```
console.log('character :', encodingJapanese.detect(fileData));
```

So I tried to get the character encoding directly from the stream,The expected value was SJIS or UTF8, but the result was ASCII in both cases.

How can I get the character encoding from stream?